# Bot does not greet user joined when launched in web client

Tags: c#, botframework, webclient, direct-line-botframework

I have added a custom message whenever a user joins the conversation with my bot in OnMembersAdded method, it also works well over Bot Emulator , bot sends a proactive message greeting user with his/her name.

But on Web Client bot sends the message when user types first and then it sends a greeting message which abrupt s the flow.

my code for handling user joined session

```
 protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
             foreach (var member in membersAdded)
                {
                    if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hi {firstName.ToLower()}, I am at your service."), cancellationToken);
                    }
                }


        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120#issuecomment-516056614

Comment: Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a store method in the client side and with that you can send the greeting message oneventasync method through the bot framework.

***following code is  working solution***:

**store method on Client Site:**

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                payload: {
                    name: 'webchat/join',
                    value:{
                    "userName":name,
                    "eMail":mail 
                    },

                }
            });

        }
```

**Server side - Bot code :**

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var objectdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());

            data _data = new data();
            _data.username = objectdata["userName"];
            _data.eMail= objectdata["eMail"];


            if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join")
            {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Good Morning! \n\n **{_data.username}** \n {WelcomeText}"), cancellationToken);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this working example and explanation on how to send a [Welcome Message Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) from WebChat.

Comment: And this Conversation update will be used inside onMessageActivityAsync method?

Comment: Are you using botframework V3 or V4, and do you have the template/project from which you based your solution on? If so i can check them and get back to you exactly where to use it

Comment: i am using v4 , i am using dispatch model got from azure

Comment: There seems to be an issue with WebChat and welcome event, please check my updated answer to solve this

Comment: @MarcAsmar There isn't an issue so much as it's intended design. Your answer also had a broken link, which I fixed. The way to do this in Web Chat is as the example shows; specifically send the welcome message event.